# If $(U,W)$ is i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$ then $UW$ has PDF $f_{UW}(t)=-\ln t$ on $ (0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $U,V,W \sim R(0,1)$ independent. Show that the density of $UW$ is
>
> $f_{UW}(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}-\ln t, \text{ if }t \in (0,1)\\ 0
> \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ else. }\end{matrix}\right.$

I'm not quite sure how to show that correctly. I think we can write this as

$$P\left(U \cdot W <y\right) = \int P\left(U \cdot W <y \mid W=w\right)f_W(w) \,\, dw$$
 and then show that it's continuous and if that's the case we have that the density of $UW$ is $f_{UW}(t)$.

But it seems like this will be even more complicated to show : /

Maybe there is a more clear and easier way to do this?

Comment: "But it seems like this will be even more complicated to show" Well, no it will not.

Comment: What do you mean by $R(0,1)$?

Comment: @Falrach example $X \sim R(0,1)$ means that random variable $X$ is equally distributed in interval from zero to one

Comment: Thanks, i know this as $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$

Comment: See this also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561691/pdf-of-a-function/2561703#2561703.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $t\in (0,1)$ the distribution function is $$\Bbb{P}(UW < t) = \int_0^1 \Bbb{P}(U < \frac{t}{\omega})d\omega  = \int_t^1 \frac{t}{\omega}d\omega + t = t (\ln(1)- \ln(t)) + t = -t\ln(t)+t$$
So we get the density through differentiation:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Bbb{P}(UW<t) = 1 -\ln(t) - \frac{t}{t} = -\ln(t)$$
On the complement of $(0,1)$ the density is obviously zero.